# How to prevent my android activity from going to isFinishing()?

Tags: android, performance, android-alertdialog, activity-lifecycle, android-background

I have activity1 and activity2. Activity2 contains an custom alert dialog, when i come from activity1 to activity 2, I am getting the alert perfectly. Butt when i go back to activity1 (when pressed on back button) and then return to activity2, i am able to get the alert only 3-4 times. After that it goes to isFinishing() state. How could I prevent my activity going to isFinishing() state?

(I am calling the alert using handler thread)

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think its not late. The best way to prevent alert going back to onfinishing() is declare the alert dialog as an activity.